# The same OAuth token fetch fails with .NET Core 3.1 but works with full .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, salesforce

I'm upgrading our code from .NET Framework to .NET Core 3.1 and have run into a problem in one of our services which handles authentication with Salesforce API.

The Salesforce token endpoint returns an error

> Bad Request: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"authentication failure"}

when I'm running my code in .NET Core. When I use the full framework, it works just fine.

```
_tokenClient = factory.CreateClient("TokenClient");
_tokenClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_options.TokenUrl);

HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
      {"grant_type", "password"},
      {"client_id", _options.ClientId},
      {"client_secret", _options.ClientSecret},
      {"username", _options.Username},
      {"password", _options.Password},
});

var response = await _tokenClient.PostAsync("token", content);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full .NET Framework handles url encoding somehow differently than net-core. On of my parameters contained `&amp;` which caused this issue. Changing it to just `&` solved it...